# SMTPClient: Error al enviar el correo .cs

Tags: c#, smtp

estoy tratando de hacer un envio de correo sencillo instanciando un cliente SMTP en .cs, el codigo es el siguiente

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
#endregion

namespace ST_aa2380eff24a48889fa53256556a6d21
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
        /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
         * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
         * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
         * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
         * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
         * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
         * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
         * 
         * Example of reading from a variable:
         *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of writing to a variable:
         *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
         * 
         * Example of reading from a package parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
         *  
         * Example of reading from a project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
         * */

        #endregion

        #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
        /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
         * 
         * Example of firing an error event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
         * 
         * Example of firing an information event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
         * 
         * Example of firing a warning event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
         * */
        #endregion

        #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
        /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
         * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
         * 
         * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         *
         * Example of using a File connection manager
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         * */
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
        /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
        /// To open Help, press F1.
        /// </summary>
        public void Main()
        {
            try
            {

                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.xxx", "Script message", "Hola mundo");
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587);
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.EnableSsl = false;
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |=      SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxx@xxxx.xxx.xx", "xxxx.xxxx");

                client.Send(msg);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
```

Cabe destacar que estan importadas todas las librerias pertinentes

Y el mensaje de error es

```
System.Net.Mail.smtpException: Error al procesar. La respuesta del sevidor fueL 5.7.3 STARTTLS is required to send mail,.[BN9PR03CA0792.namprd03.prod.outlook.com]
```

Anteriormente teniamos un script mas complejo y dejo de funcionar, y yo he intentado con varios codigos diferentes y ninguno me funciona, si pueden dejarme algun aporte o punto de inicio, estaria eternamente agradecido.

**ACTUALIZACION**

Se agrego el codigo completo del script
El script en cuestion, corre dentro de un script como resultado de un JOB de SQL Server.
Dicho correo es una cuenta de Outlook la cual anteriormente funcionaba y de la noche a la mañana dejo de hacerlo, ese mismo correo se encuentra configurado en diferentes aplicativos corportativos, y funcionan todos menos en este.
El script que coloque es uno sencillo de envio de correos, puesto que el error que tengo viene siendo a la hora de mandarlo, y de lograr encontrar la falla aqui, podria corregirla en el JOB en produccion, actualmente estoy trabajando en desarrollo para solventar la falla.

--Los otros aplicativos usan SMTP+TLS para conectarse

Comment: Hola! Seguro que debes usar SSL y TLS en la conexión a outlook?

Comment: He visto ejemplos sobre esto y no usan `ServicePointManager`. Intenta agregar esta línea: `client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;`

Comment: El servicio de outlook especifica que hay que usar TLS en el puerto 587, asi mismo lo que comenta @Mateo no me funciono, me da el mismo mensaje de error

Comment: No sé que podría ser. Parece [no ser posible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630101/13419694) pero también hay personas que afirman que les funciona.

Comment: Es un correo de gmail debes establecer que permites envio de correos https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mailbox-migration/migrating-imap-mailboxes/prepare-gmail-or-g-suite-accounts

Comment: Agrega mas informacion a tu pregunta, en donde estas haciendo pruebas local o en produccion, y muestra todo el codigo involucrado.

Comment: Listo, actualice la pregunta y explique un poco mas el contexto @MiguelZarate

Comment: Usar TLS no implica usar SSL, son cosas diferentes. YO tengo clientes usando outlook que se conectan por el 587 con TLS **sin SSL**. Prueba esta configuración con cualquier cliente de correo y te dirá si funciona o no sin tener que pasar por tu código.

Comment: @Alfabravo hice lo que me indicaste, desactive el ssl y active el tls, pero ninguna de las versiones de Tls me es compatible, ahora me da una excepcion de ese tipo (modifique el codigo y la pregunta), sabes como puedo solventarla? Y gracias de antemano c:

Comment: TLS se habilita usando `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;` y esa instrucción que tienes no parece estar habiiltando nada; por eso se queja

Comment: @Alfabravo Puse lo que me colocaste, pero no me reconoce el `SecurityProtocolType.Tls13` y por ende me da un error de compilacion, asi mismo sin ese Tls13 me sigue lanzando la misma excepcion comentada arriba

Comment: @DavidOrtuño entonces tienes una versión de .NET vieja que no lo soporta, quítalo y deja las otras dos...

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, casualmente uno de los correos se envio esta mañana (uno que no modifique y que no usaba TLS pero igualmente se envio) y me di cuenta por los detalles del correo que  **outlook** trabaja con TLS 1.2, por lo tanto con el **SSL activado** y el **TLS 1.2** si me estan funcionando los envios, agradeceria que escribas una respuesta para poder cerrar este hilo, y agradezco inmensamente tus aportes y tu apoyo, feliz dia

Comment: Hecho! Me alegra que te haya funcionado :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por experiencia (hasta un plug-in de Jenkins he tenido que ayudar a modificar), sé que Outlook suele usar STARTTLS sin SSL para conexiones SMTP. Montar la conexión SSL y comunicarse cifrando con TLS son cosas diferentes y se habilitan de forma diferente.

Así pues, mi sugerencia es que no actives SSL y que habilites TLS (tu código no está asignándole nada a nadie con la instrucción que pones). Prueba con

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Dependiendo de la versión de .NET, puedes incluir Tls13 (que es más reciente y seguro), aunque no sé si outlook ya lo soporta :P